# 14.04 Unity accessing application menu with keyboard

Tags: shortcut-keys, menu, appmenu

I need to be able to access the applications menu using only the keyboard in unity as my mouse pointer has started to get stuck on the hand icon and I can't click anything.

As the keyboard shortcuts suggests (hold down super to see) I can hold down the ALT key bring up the application menu headers, but I can't select any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt exposes the menu, note the underlined letter for each menu item. Then press that letter while still holding the alt key.

That will expose the menu, release alt + the letter key & use down & up arrow keys to navigate the menu, enter key to use selected item

Comment: There are no underlined letters in the application menu for chromium?? That's strange I've only just noticed that. Works for firefox though, cheers

Comment: Spotify also does not have underlined letters on the application menu when alt is held down, and so is not usable via keyboard shortcuts